If G is a product of two subgroups, must one of them be normal?
I have the following problem with semidirect products which seems like a basic question in group theory, but I could not find the answer.
Let $G$ be a group, and let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be two subgroups of $G$. If we assume that the multiplication map
$H_1\times H_2 \to G: (a,b)\mapsto a\cdot b$
is bijective, does that imply that at least one the two subgroups $H_1$ or $H_2$ is a normal subgroup of $G$?

no, you can take $G=S_n$ ($n$ large enough), $H_1=S_{n-1}$, $H_2$ the cyclic permutations of 1,2,...,$n$.

That is a very convincing example! Thank you! If you want to write it as an answer, I can accept it.

done (I know I shouldn't use comments to answer the questions :)

No, you can take $G=S_n$ ($n$ large enough), $H_1=S_{n-1}$ and $H_2$ the group of cyclic permutations of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.

Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, it serms that I cannot accept it as someone closed my question as it does not meet thr high standards of math stackexchange :-/

never mind  I think I accepted it. :-)

As the existing answer points out, the answer is "no". The answer is still "no" if we assume that the intersection $H_1\cap H_2$ is trivial (this mimics another of the semi-direct product properties). Indeed, groups which decompose as $G=H_1H_2$ with $H_1\cap H_2=1$ are called Zappa-Szép products, and are studied in their own right.
For example, Philip Hall proved that every soluble group is a Zappa-Szép product of a Hall $p'$-subgroup and a Sylow $p$-subgroup; see wikipedia for details (although neither Hall nor this article make reference to this interpretation of his result).

In the question the OP is assuming the multiplication map is bijective, which forces $H_1 \cap H_2 = 1$. (This also happens in the other answer)

@testaccount Ah, of course! I missed that :-)
